# Warning for transfering maven-metadata.xml failed and errors for resolving denpencies when building

Tags: java, xml, maven, building, saiku

Download codes from Saiku repository on GitHub. Switch to branch 2.6.x.

Use command "./saiku build all" to do building.

However, there are so many warning and errors there:

```html
<pre>
 [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.olap4j:olap4j-xmla:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to pentaho-third-party (http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/third-party/): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/third-party/org/olap4j/olap4j-xmla/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is : 503 , ReasonPhrase: Service Temporarily Unavailable.
[WARNING] .. from/to alabs-repo (http://repo.analytical-labs.com/repo/): Connection to http://repo.analytical-labs.com refused
...
Downloading: http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/third-party/org/olap4j/olap4j-xmla/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/olap4j-xmla-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
...
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5:44.581s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 18 23:57:43 CST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/18M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project saiku-bi-platform-plugin-p5: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.saiku:saiku-bi-platform-plugin-p5:jar:2.6.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.saiku:saiku-service:jar:2.6.1-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.saiku:saiku-web:jar:2.6.1-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.saiku:saiku-olap-util:jar:2.6.1-SNAPSHOT (compile), pentaho:cpf-core:jar:REFACTOR-SNAPSHOT (compile), pentaho:cpf-pentaho5:jar:REFACTOR-SNAPSHOT (compile), pentaho:mondrian:jar:3.6.5 (compile), eigenbase:eigenbase-properties:jar:1.1.0.10924 (compile), eigenbase:eigenbase-resgen:jar:1.3.0.11873 (compile), eigenbase:eigenbase-xom:jar:1.3.0.11999 (compile), org.olap4j:olap4j-xmla:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1 (compile), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14 (compile), pentaho:pentaho-platform-api:jar:5.0.0 (provided), pentaho:pentaho-platform-core:jar:5.0.0 (provided), pentaho:pentaho-platform-extensions:jar:5.0.0 (provided), com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.11 (compile), com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.11 (compile), com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.11 (compile), org.jvnet:mimepull:jar:1.6 (compile), com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.11 (compile), com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:jar:1.11 (compile), com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.11 (compile), javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4 (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE (compile), com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.5.0 (compile), com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:jar:5.5.0 (compile), rhino:js:jar:1.7R2 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.saiku:saiku-service:jar:2.6.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.saiku:saiku-service:pom:2.6.1-SNAPSHOT from/to pentaho-third-party (http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/third-party/): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/third-party/org/saiku/saiku-service/2.6.1-SNAPSHOT/saiku-service-2.6.1-SNAPSHOT.pom. Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException  
</pre>
```

Questions:

1. What is the difference between "maven-metadata.xml" and "olap4j-xmla-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom" file?
2. Why it is 503 code when responding for downloading  "maven-metadata.xml"?
3. Why errors?
4. Is there any other maven repository to resolve those dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re *2.* & *3.*:

```
(http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/third-party/): Failed to transfer file: ...
  Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Temporarily Unavailable.

(http://repo.analytical-labs.com/repo/): 
  Connection to http://repo.analytical-labs.com refused
```

Re *4.*:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.olap4j

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Vittery

I found it can also be resolved by http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/ or  http://nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni/.

I used  http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/. However, I also need to change org.olap4j:olap4j-xmla:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT to org.olap4j:olap4j-xmla:1.2.0.